# ¿ Como Activar el submit oculto con otro boton usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que busco es activar el submit oculto con otro boton. por ejemplo: cuando se llenan los datos de un formulario este sea enviado con un boton Generico ya que este boton generico evalua o valida todos los campos; por lo tanto busco que el boton generico evalue si hay archivo en el ( file ) para luego enviar todo los datos de dichos campos.

NOTA: 
    1 * Busco Validar el ( file ) para obligar al usuario a subir un archivo
    2 * El archivo debe enviarse con un boton generico que recoje todos los campos cuyo proposito es validar y enviar con un solo boton

```js
    const subir_btn = document.getElementById('subir_btn');
    const send = document.getElementById('send');

    send.addEventListener("click",function () {
     subir_btn.click();
    });
```

```html
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Subir Archivo de su Propuesta </label>
       <div class=""><br>
     <form name="enviar_archivo_frm" method="POST" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          <input type="file" name="archivo_fls" accept=".pdf,.doc">
          <input type="submit" id="subir_btn" name="subir_btn" Value="Subir Archivo" hidden="hidden">
     </form>
   </div>
</div> 
      
<div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="send" type="button">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const subir_btn = document.getElementById('subir_btn');
    const send = document.getElementById('send');

    send.addEventListener("click",function () {
     subir_btn.click();
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Subir Archivo de su Propuesta </label>
       <div class=""><br>
     <form name="enviar_archivo_frm" method="POST" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          <input type="file" name="archivo_fls" required accept=".pdf,.doc">
          <input type="submit" id="subir_btn" name="subir_btn" Value="Subir Archivo" hidden="hidden">
     </form>
   </div>
</div> 
      
<div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="send" type="button">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
</div>
```

Puedes utilizar `required` de `HTML5` para validar que esté lleno el campo

```
<input type="file" name="archivo_fls" required accept=".pdf,.doc">
```

Comment: Ok. pero me gustaria usar validanes  con html ya que el usuario puede modificar el codigo por inspector de elementos; como haria para aplicarlo con javascript

Comment: Estas hablando de usuarios con un nivel medio de conocimientos web, si sabe utilizar la consola de los navegadores, ni con JS te vas a salvar de saltarse las reglas. Comúnmente el usuario final no sabe en muchas ocasiones ni usar el navegador.

Comment: Claro que entiendo tu parte pero seria bueno no dejar tan vulnerable la web. Es bueno aplicarle un poco mas de complejida. tienes idea como hacerlo

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con los dos, la mayoria de usuarios no sabrian utilizar el inspector de elementos, pero hay algunos que si saben y se llaman hackers.  La validacion tiene que ser en ambos el navegador como en el servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres, yo lo haría del siguiente modo:

- Iniciaría con el botón encargado de enviar el formulario en estado desactivado.
- Haría que su activación dependiese de si hay archivos seleccionados en el `input` encargado de recoger los archivos.

Esa es la práctica habitual que vemos en las páginas que usamos a diario. De ese modo, no se incentiva al usuario a ejecutar acciones que no funcionarían o que no estarían permitidas, porque la condición (que haya archivos seleccionados) no se cumple.

```js
var inputFile = document.getElementById("ibxFile");
inputFile.addEventListener('change', checkFiles);

function checkFiles(event) {
  var isFilesEmpty = this.files.length == 0 ? true : false;
  var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("send");
  btnEnviar.disabled = isFilesEmpty;

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Subir Archivo de su Propuesta </label>
  <div class=""><br>
    <form name="enviar_archivo_frm" method="POST" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="ibxFile" name="archivo_fls" required accept=".pdf,.doc" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="send" type="button" disabled>GUARDAR DATOS</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Es valido tambien asi que te dare punto por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

**LISTO AQUI LA VALIDACION CON JAVASCRIPT**

```js
const subir_btn = document.getElementById('subir_btn');
const send = document.getElementById('send');

send.addEventListener("click",function () {
var x = document.getElementById("archivo_fls").value;
if(x.length=='')
 throw new Error('Error: Debes de Asignar un archivo obligatoriamente');
subir_btn.click();
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group"><!-- -- INICIO Darwuin con JAVASCRIPT -- -->
   <label class="control-label">Subir Archivo de su Propuesta </label>
   <div class=""><br>
 <form name="enviar_archivo_frm" method="POST" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" id="archivo_fls" name="archivo_fls" required accept=".pdf,.doc">
  <input type="submit" id="subir_btn" name="subir_btn"  Value="Subir Archivo" hidden="hidden">
  <div id="demo"></div>
 </form>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="send" type="button">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
</div>
```